# Are repulsorlifts anti-gravity?

Tags: star-wars, artificial-gravity

I know this sounds like a stupid question, but I just wanted to confirm if they are the same thing. In new canon, anti-gravity is never mentioned.

Comment: Unclear. What precisely do you mean by "anti-gravity?" For example, does walking up the stairs using your legs count as "anti-gravity?" Do lighter-than-air objects such as hot-air balloons count as "anti-gravity?" Do powered or un-powered flight? What about a fictional technology or material that makes one *transparent* to gravity? What about a fictional technology or material that has "negative mass" (i.e. accelerates under the influence of gravity, except *away* from mass, instead of towards it). Or do you just care about the word "anti-gravity" rather than the concept described by it?

Comment: @Lexible Anti-gravity is a standard word. You can find it in Oxford dictionary as well as Wikipedia.

Comment: @CaptainCold anti-gravity is a poorly conceived word, and poorly theorized concept. Your comment (and the sources you cite) does not clarify what the OP means or is interested in.

Answer (score 8):

**Repulsorlift technology is explicitly called out in the [Star Wars: The Force Awakens: Incredible Cross-Sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_Incredible_Cross-Sections) as being a technology based on anti-gravity.**

[image]

> *"Repulsorlifts allow a craft to hover or fly over a planet's surface by
>   pushing against its gravity, producing thrust"*

That being said, it would appear that the thrust doesn't have to be directly downwards towards the centre-mass. It can be used for directional thrust as well

[image]

There's also the following excerpt from the [junior novelisation of Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(junior_novelization))

> Fett was followed by a floating slab of metal that Luke couldn’t make
>   out. The floating slab was followed by two blue-uniformed Cloud City
>   guards, who held the end of the slab and appeared to be guiding it
>   through the hallway. **Luke realized the slab was resting on a thin
>   repulsor sled, an antigravity device used to transport heavy objects.**

Answer (score -2):

No it is not anti gravity because it does not make use of anti matter, instead it uses air to push against the ground.

Comment: You should [edit] in some evidence to back this up because it appears to contradict canon as shown in the other answer.

Comment: I'm curious what anti-gravity has to do with anti-matter, too. Actually, not that curious.